# How do I avoid being tossed around so much?

Tags: super-smash-bros

When playing Smash Bros against two or more bots or human opponents, I often find myself being tossed around endlessly between them until I get thrown out of the stage. No amount of button-mashing can save me in those situations.

I mostly use Luigi or Fox, and this happens to me with both characters.

Comment: `No amount of button-mashing can save me in those situations` I hope button mashing isn't how you got yourself in this mess in the first place...

Comment: ...maybe. :p Nah, it usually happens when I force myself to fight at close range. I'm much better at sniping from the sidelines and picking off weak rivals, but it's boring so I don't want to be doing that all the time.

Comment: Picking on the lonely (weakened) rivals, then getting bored, rushing into the fray, and finally getting my behind handed down to me, is pretty much how I play the game as well... You just reminded me of countless hours of frustration and loss of self-esteem... D:

Comment: Unless you are much much better than the people you are playing with, you are not going to win any 1v2 encounter anytime soon.  "The only winning move is not to play," i.e. don't get into those situations.  Can you provide a bit more information?  Are you just playing a free for all where you get ganged up on all the time or are you actively seeking 1v2 battles?

Comment: Is this a 2v1 or a FFA where they're camping at opposite ends of the stage?

Comment: I would expect this to happen in 2v1, but this happens in FFAs too. My rivals usually seem to have plenty of time to fight each other while I fly (helplessly stunned) back and forth between them.

Comment: The important difference is that in a 2v1 you should try to keep them apart so you can fight them one at a time, while in a FFA you should try to keep them together so they fight each other as well as you.

Answer (score 4):

There's not a whole lot you can do if you have multiple enemies beating on you from different directions. You do have some limited options though.

- Try to shield. If you can get your shield up and successfully block an attack, quickly roll away from the bad zone. You probably should not try to grab unless you know you can time the throw perfectly to resist the bystander's attack (and can deal with the shieldgrab's half damage).
- If your damage is low and everyone's close together, try to SDI through the guy hitting you towards their other side. This might be more effective than SDI'ing away because you're not moving towards the other guy and the first attacker may not be expecting it, but watch out for attacks that have sweetspots up close.
- If you have room to fly between the two enemies, try to SDI downwards so you're closer to the ground and so have a chance of landing and teching earlier. High-gravity characters have a better chance here.
- For Luigi and Fox specifically, here are some of their fastest attacks you can try and use to hit the opponents, measured in frames:

  - Luigi

    - Neutral attack: hits on 3
    - Neutral air: hits on 4
    - Up air: hits on 3
    - Up special: hits on 3
    - Down special: hits on 1
  - Fox

    - Neutral attack: hits on 4
    - Neutral aerial: hits on 5
    - Back aerial: hits on 5
    - Down aerial: hits on 5
    - Down special: hits on 1
  - As seen above, both Luigi's and Fox's down specials hit instantly. Time them correctly and the opponent can only trade with you at worst.

Comment: If you're flying at an opponent you should probably focus on the range and priority of your attacks before the frame they trigger on. Even if your attack triggers on frame 1, that won't do you any good if you have to be touching your opponent to hit them and they can hit you with the tip of their sword etc

Comment: This is true, but without animation data I only know the "radii" of hitboxes and hurtboxes so I can't really measure range, and so couldn't really do a comparison.

Comment: Brian makes a very good point.  Both Fox and Luigi's down specials are **terrible** moves for making an approach because of how limited their range is.  Fox's reflector is a viable button mash escape move for when the enemy is on top of you because of its speed to knockback ratio, but Luigi's is much too slow to be useful except as a flashy and too risky combo finsher.  For both of them, approaching from the side or below is much safer than from above.  Both have back aerials with decent hitboxes.  Fox's up aerial has very large hit boxes as well.

Comment: I've addressed this in my answer but passively shielding is a terrible idea in a 1 v many fight.  Shields temporarily prevent you from taking damage in exchange for rendering you immobile and unable to avoid further attacks.  You may be able to get away in a 1v1 but the odds go down dramatically in a 1v2.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are deliberately putting yourself into 1v2 fights while you are not yet ready for them.  In order to come out of a 1v2 fight successfully, your 1v1 fights need to be nearly flawless.  A 1v2 is not merely twice as hard as a 1v1 - it is orders of magnitude harder.  Whereas in a 1v1 you can trade hits or take the occasional hit and recover, with multiple opponents you don't have that luxury.  You don't even have the luxury of using your high cooldown power finishers (Luigi's up B or Fox's up smash) because the other guy can punish you for killing his teammate.  If either one of your opponents is evenly matched to you the fight will be nearly unwinnable.

Now assuming your 1v1 skills are good enough, you still need to fight strategically to win.  Unless friendly fire is on, you don't want your opponents to be grouped together - their hitboxes will just stack and there will be very little you can do.

Your priority is to separate your opponents, and then get K.O.'s as efficiently as possible.  Typically this means targeting the weakest of the opponents.  Use the barest minimum amount of effort to keep the stronger opponents from getting too close (toss projectiles their way or a good spacing aerial attack - back aerials work fairly well for Luigi and Fox) while you try to go for low-percentage gimps on the weaker opponent.

Also, pick a large stage to give you room to escape when you need it.  Hyrule Castle or Sector Z are good candidates.  Maybe Zebes if it is allowed and just try to be king of the top platform and let the acid do the K.O.'s for you.

If it's a free for all stock match, just run away from everything - last survivor wins.  You have no incentive to actually get k.o's in that mode.  If it's a time match, just treat it as a team game with friendly fire on and target the weakest player as described above.  Use projectiles to steal K.O.'s from people by hitting people already hopelessly off stage.

Other tips:

Focus on dodging, spacing, and positioning.  You want to avoid shielding or rolling if at all possible - even in a 1v1 a single opponent can put quite a bit of pressure on a shield.  With 2 opponents hammering on a shield at once, you are just going to get stun-locked until your shield breaks or someone grabs you and throws you.

Abuse throws as long as you are not Link, Samus, or Yoshi.  Not only are throws one of the fastest attacks, they work great for positioning your opponents (e.g. to separate them), and most throws turn the thrown opponent into a projectile which adds additional protection.

Comment: Just run away if its a free for all stock match? I much prefer grabbing one character and throwing them at the other one. If you run away the whole game other players will often team up on you for being a coward.

Comment: And that's the reason a FFA stock match is a dumb mode.  When I do FFA it's always timed - everyone gets to play for the whole time and there is an incentive to fight.  There is simply no sensible way to play FFA stock besides being an opportunistic douche who never engages except when the opponent is distracted.  If you are going to team up you might as well play a team match.

Comment: Thankfully, everyone I've played with has been fairly wrathful towards players who just run away or hide on the edge and spam ranged attacks.

Comment: Isn't easier to just play a timed match?  Highest score wins, and meanwhile the people who get knocked out first don't have to twiddle their thumbs while watching the last 2 people have their 1v1.

Comment: I've found that matches based on kills just result in the most opportunistic player winning. The winner is usually the one who can steal the most kills from other players.

Comment: Honestly, there is no way to have a "winner" in a FFA anyways.  A timed match is more fun because more people are involved instead of having people drop out, and stealing kills is better than camping at least.  If you really want to a match where "winner" means something you need to do a round robin 1v1.